# Automate seedlist in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

I have a question. We have been having issues making sure our entire DCOM team receives an email after each deployment (our seedlist) Is there a way that I can automate seedlists so i don’t have to manually add them to each mailing or journey? Especially now that i am doing a lot of dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, automating seedlists in SFMC is not easily possible. Secondly, the seedlist concept in a highly personalised and data driven environment might make little sense.

When sending out emails to your audience, you might have a number of content blocks, which are shown conditionally, based on the information about the recipient. Let's say you have 12 content blocks, out of which, 3 are selected - which provide best match for the recipient. This might be based on preferences, browsing behaviour, previous purchases etc. Imagine this across a sendout to 500.000 recipients. This leaves a number of different options sent to thousands of people.

Which option would you send to your seedlist? Adding recipients to a sendable data extension might not be technically difficult (you can use SQL to append records from a seedlist data extension). But how would you ensure the right data? Especially if your sendouts differ in what columns are present in your sendable data extension.

Answer (score 0):

We seed our Marketing team each email & it is automated in the sense that we include them every sendable DE through SQL in SFMC or on our CRM side (we are not using Salesforce CRM). But, the catch is that the list has to be updated by the Marketing Team.